# Generic Typing confusion

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Given the interfaces and types below, I would *like* to have an interface for a PartyDao:

```
public interface IPartyDao<IdT> : IDao<Party<IdT>> where IdT : struct{}
```

I cannot do this because the compiler thinks that a Party is not convertible into an EntityWithTypedId. To look at the signature of a Party, it *seems* that Party IS an EntityWithTypedId and therefore s/b convertible into one.

Besides the fact that the compiler is always right, why is it right in this case? Is there a fix?

Much of the nastiness, at least aesthetically, comes from using IdT, but

```
// IdT is just the id, usually either an int or Guid
//
public interface IEntityWithTypedId<out TId> where TId : struct 
{
    TId Id { get; }
}

// base impl
public abstract class EntityWithTypedId<TId> : IEntityWithTypedId<TId> where TId:struct 
{ 
    //..  
}

// Party *IS* of the right lineage
public class Party<IdT> : EntityWithTypedId<IdT> where IdT : struct
{
    //..  
}

// 
public interface IDao<T, in IdT> 
    where T : EntityWithTypedId<IdT> 
    where IdT : struct
{
    //..  
}
```

Comment: When compiling your code I get an error indicating `IDao` requires two generic arguments, not the error you're describing.

Comment: Also note, you state in the comments that `TId` may be a `string` - `string` is not a struct, so that restriction will not allow you to use a `string` for `TId`.

Comment: @Gjeltema. Good spot on out of date documentation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your interface to:

```
public interface IPartyDao<IdT> : IDao<Party<IdT>, IdT> 
    where IdT : struct { }
```

And it will compile.

The code you posted here doesn't have a second generic argument passed to `IDao`.

In order to get the error you're seeing you'd need to pass a type other than `IdT` as the second generic argument.  If you pass, say, an `int` (to get the first compiler error to go away) then the error would be that you couldn't convert a `Party<IdT>` to an `EntityWithTypedId<int>`.  The generic arguments of those types need to match (since they're neither covariant nor contravariant in their generic argument).

Comment: how did you even... did you just reverse-engineer the right question from the error AND answer it?

Comment: @Servy. That *was* impressive! Do you see any opportunities for co or contra variance here above what I've got? Cheers

Comment: @Berryl No, as the types aren't interfaces, and only interfaces can be co/contra variant.  Concrete types must be invariant, and it's `EntityWithTypedId` that's generating the error for you here.